# Getting the most recent rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm working on some news section for my php application , and I want write a function for user to be able to get most recent 10 news and later on when user demands to see more news the function returns recent news from 10 to 20 and so on .
considering my table is like so

```
+++++News_table++++++++
+news_ID
+news_title
+news_desc
+date_modified
++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I've searched for MySQL queries but I only found this

```
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit 10 ;
```

but this query only return the first 10 item , and if I want to get next 10 news in same manner (news 11 to 20 ) it's obsolete .
How should i write my query ?

Comment: Take a look at **OFFSET** if you want to keep getting 10 elements, or just remove **LIMIT** from your query if you want them all..

Comment: How did you implement the query in your php script. Your query needs to be variable depending on user actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `offset`:

```
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit 0, 10; // 1 - 10
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit 10, 10; // 11 - 20
```

If I expect in PHP `$_GET['page']` variable to go thru pages, with values 1, 2, etc., the query will be:

```
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit ((int)$_GET['page'] - 1) * 10, 10;
```

OR

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? ($_GET['page'] - 1) * 10 : 0;

SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit $page, 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit accepts two parameters as well:

```
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit 10, 10;
//starts from 11th and return 10 following rows
```

Also use `DESC`, not `DEC` in your `order by`.

Comment: mysql has indexes from 0, limit `11,10` returns records 12-21.

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

Answer (score 0):

The limit 10,10 mean you get result from 10 to next 10 record. Read manual [limit](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

```
 SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DESC limit 10, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime user selects page 2

```
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DEC limit 0, 10;
```

then

```
SELECT new_title , news_desc FROM News_table order by date_modified DEC limit 11, 20;
```

and so on